# Jquery Ajax get url 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, url

I got a 400 bad request error when I tried to get information from an url. Here is my code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

function searchData()
{
    dname = document.getElementById('dataname').value;

    $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/package_search?q=" + dname,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                contentType:"application/json",
                headers: { "Authorization": "123456789123456" },
                error:function(e){
                    console.log(e);
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    var name = "<ul id='list'>";

                        if (data.length !== 0) {

                            for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                                name += "<li>"+(j+1)+":"+ data[j] +">" ;
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            name = "Sorry, there is no data";
                        }

                    name += "</ul><hr>";


                    $('#result').append(name);
                }
            });

        return false;

}
```

And I got:
[image]

I tried http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/package_search?q=air through google chrome and it gives me the good result, so it is not the problem of url.

Anyone has some ideas??
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem is that CKAN api does not support disabling caching in the way jquery does it. So I have to set cache: true

Thanks to Brian's idea=>
[AJAX call error - status of 400 (Bad Request)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29503984/ajax-call-error-status-of-400-bad-request)